# Undefined variable error returning record listing page in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel

I'm having a problem with my `Huntercontroller` functions: `store()`, `update()` and `destroy()` display the following error message: `Undefined variable $hunter` on the `index.blade.php` page.

On the `index.blade.php` page, the error that appears is the following:

```
<?php $__currentLoopData = $hunter; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $hxh): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
```

Since this line points to a `@foreach($hunter as $hxh)` to view the database records. I don't understand why this is happening, `update()` and `destroy()` even with this problem I realize that they run, I just don't say the same about `store()`.

---

- `web.php`

```
Route::controller(HunterController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'index');
    Route::get('/create', 'create');
    Route::get('/update/{id}', 'edit');
    Route::post('create', 'store');
    Route::patch('/update/{id}', 'update');
    Route::delete('/delete/{id}', 'destroy'); 
});
```

- `HunterController.php`

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validations = $request->validate(
        [
            'name_hunter' => 'required|max:50',
            'year_hunter' => 'required|numeric',
            'height_hunter' => 'required|numeric',
            'weight_hunter' => 'required|numeric',
            'type_hunter' => 'required|max:30',
            'type_nen' => 'required|max:30',
            'type_blood' => 'required|max:3',
        ]);
        HunterModel::saved($validations);
        return view('index');
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $validations = $request->validate(
        [
            'name_hunter' => 'required|max:50',
            'year_hunter' => 'required|numeric',
            'height_hunter' => 'required|numeric',
            'weight_hunter' => 'required|numeric',
            'type_hunter' => 'required|max:30',
            'type_nen' => 'required|max:30',
            'type_blood' => 'required|max:3',
        ]);
        HunterModel::where('id',$id)->update($validations);
        return view ('index');     
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        HunterModel::where('id',$id)->delete();
        return view('index');     
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... why are your processing routes returning a view instead of a redirect?  your `index` view seems to require some data that you are not passing, you probably want to redirect to the index route which will return the index view with the data it needs

Comment: As lagbox is saying, `store()`, `update()` and `destroy()` should call `return redirect()->route('hunters.index')` (or similar), not `view('index')`. Also, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73627919/edit) and include your `public function index()`, and the code from `index.blade.php`. Right now, you're showing the compiled version from `storage/views`, since that is where Laravel points its errors to, but your actual code is in `resources/views/index.blade.php`. Also, you can use a Resource Controller: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validations = $request->validate(
        [
            'name_hunter' => 'required|max:50',
            'year_hunter' => 'required|numeric',
            'height_hunter' => 'required|numeric',
            'weight_hunter' => 'required|numeric',
            'type_hunter' => 'required|max:30',
            'type_nen' => 'required|max:30',
            'type_blood' => 'required|max:3',
        ]);
        HunterModel::saved($validations);
        return redirect()->to('/'); 
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $validations = $request->validate(
        [
            'name_hunter' => 'required|max:50',
            'year_hunter' => 'required|numeric',
            'height_hunter' => 'required|numeric',
            'weight_hunter' => 'required|numeric',
            'type_hunter' => 'required|max:30',
            'type_nen' => 'required|max:30',
            'type_blood' => 'required|max:3',
        ]);
        HunterModel::where('id',$id)->update($validations);
        return redirect()->to('/');      
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        HunterModel::where('id',$id)->delete();
        return redirect()->to('/');     
    }
```